# Check If UpperCase Column Name Exists In A Datable

Tags: vb.net

I am using the code below to check if a column name exists in another database.
I am having an issue where the column name in Table (topDS) is all uppercase and the column name in table (Detail) is a mix of upper and lower case. 
How can I check disregard letter case when investigating a columns collection?

```
For Each col As DataColumn In topDS.Tables(0).Columns
  If parsedDataset.Tables("Detail").Columns.Contains(col.ColumnName) Then
    newRow(col.ColumnName) = r(col.ColumnName).ToString
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
For Each col As DataColumn In topDS.Tables(0).Columns
 If parsedDataset.Tables("Detail").Columns.Contains(col.ColumnName) Then
  If String.Equals(newRow(col.ColumnName).ToString, r(col.ColumnName).ToString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
   'true
  End If
 End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to ensure they are both the same case when comparing.

```
For Each col As DataColumn In topDS.Tables(0).Columns
  If parsedDataset.Tables("Detail").Columns.ColumnName.ToUpper() = col.ColumnName.ToUpper() Then
    newRow(col.ColumnName) = r(col.ColumnName).ToString
  End If
Next
```